# Are the location based achievements in BL2 bugged?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

I've finished my first playthrough and I'm pretty sure i went through all areas in the game, but i can't seem to get the location based achievements like:

Urban Explorer
Arctic Explorer 
Blight Explorer

I open my map and all areas are discovered....

Any help?

Comment: The general consensus is, no. They work. Just make sure you are thorough. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87020/1134 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84873/1134

Comment: I was honestly wondering that myself when I was playing, as I was SURE I'd got everything in those three. I'll give it the old college try and see what happens. Wish me luck, gentle readers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mufasa said in the comments, they don't appear to be. Last night, I got Arctic Explorer after finding that I'd missed the exact same location as Adeese in the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87020/what-exact-locations-are-covered-by-arctic-explorer). So, just check all of the maps; if there are any areas which are undiscovered, head there. Once all areas are marked, whether they're named or not (as I recall, the location in question was NOT named), the achievement should trigger.

Comment: Yeah, the "named" part is crap, it just means clear all the fog/unexplored places from your maps.